# What's the difference between ничем and ничего?

Tags: лексикон

Both mean "nothing" as far as I understand, so what is the difference?

Comment: These are different cases of one word.

Comment: ничто:[en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE); [ru.wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Russian declension is a very complex system. Its grammatical cases (падежи) sometimes can be very tricky and confusing, however there are some rules that can help you to understand them.

In your case, you actually have the same word in two different cases. The first one, "ничем", is an instrumental grammatic case for the main - so called, nominative - case "ничего".

All six grammatic cases in order:

Именительный падеж/nominative case:

ничего

Родительный падеж/genitive case:

Ничего

Дательный падеж/dative case:

Ничему

Винительный падеж/accusative case:

Ничего

Творительный падеж/instrumental case:

Ничем

Предложный падеж/prepositional case:

(Exception)
Ни (о/в) чем

It's totally OK to say: "Он абсолютно ничего не сделал"/"He has done absolutely nothing", while "Он абсолютно ничем не сделал" is incorrect, even though the majority of Russians  would understand you.

Number of cases in Russian language can differ in different textbooks, but I cannot mention any noun that would not have any of these grammatic cases.

Comment: спасибо болщое :)

Comment: Не за что.

P.S. Кстати, слово "большое" пишется с "ш", а не "щ". Удачи в освоении.

Comment: спасибо большое again! ;)

Answer (score 2):

**ничем** is declension of **ничто** in instrumental form (see [Russian_declension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_declension)). Example: negotiations ended with nothing - переговоры закончились **ничем**.